# left margine is not working properly in ajax tab cotrol

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ajax tab control and and trying to set left margine to 100px.
but the tabs are appearing like this- 
      HomeProfileAboutmeProjectContact

```
 <ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="1119px" Height="373px" CssClass="tab">
 <ajax:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    Home
  </HeaderTemplate>
 </ajax:TabPanel>

<style type="text/css">

 .tab
 { 
   margin-left :100px;
 }
 </style>
```

Please help where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

used div tag to solve this issue-

```
<div class="tab">
```